# Whenever ansible makes changes to sshd in CentOS7 a random future play cannot connect

Tags: centos, scripting, sshd, ansible

This has been an irritating enough problem now that I thought I would finally ask the community at large what a possible solution might be.  It's even more irritating that I seem to be the only one experiencing this issue.

Essentially, anytime in CentOS 7.x, sshd configs, or any part of sshd gets modified, and the daemon gets restarted/reloaded at some "random point" in the next 3 minutes, the ssh connections all reset, and then that server is unreachable for a few seconds time via ssh.

This is especially a problem for ansible in that it needs to do these changes itself to sshd sometimes, and also reloading it (for instance in new CentOS 7x server builds).  But then in future plays it just randomly can't connect to ssh, and the it blows up the rest of the playbook/plays for that host which failed to be contacted.  This is especially bad for a large host pattern, as a few will randomly complete, but the others will fail at various stages along the playbook after sshd is manipulated.  It is of note, that nothing of the sort occurs in CentOS 5x, 6x, or even on Solaris.

The best I can do to avoid this is to create a 90 second wait after any changes to sshd, and even this isn't totally foolproof.  It makes those playbooks take 20+ minutes to run though if it's invoked 7-8 times.

Here are some facts on this environment:

All new installs are from official ISO DVD's. 
Every server is a hyper-v 2012 guest
Every server which has this problem is CentOS 7.x

Here is some actual output of the problems and some hackneyed solutions:

The failure:

```
fatal: [voltron]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "All items         completed", "results": [{"_ansible_item_result": true, "item": ["rsync", "iotop", "bind-utils", "sysstat.x86_64", "lsof"], "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to voltron closed.\r\n", "unreachable": true}]}
```

Example of one of the changes to sshd:

```
- name: Configure sshd to disallow root logins for security purposes on CentOS and Redhat 7x servers.
    lineinfile:
      backup: yes
      dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      regexp: '^(#PermitRootLogin)'
      line: "PermitRootLogin no"
      state: present
    when: (ansible_distribution == "CentOS" or "RedHat") and (ansible_distribution_major_version == "7")
    notify: sshd reload Linux 7x
```

The following handler:

```
- name: sshd reload Linux 7x
   systemd:
     state: restarted
     daemon_reload: yes
     name: sshd
```

Finally my ghetto fix to try and account for this problem:

```
- name: Wait a bit on CentOS/Redhat 7x servers to ensure changes don't mess up ssh and screw up further plays.
    pause:
      seconds: 90
    when: (ansible_distribution == "CentOS" or "RedHat") and (ansible_distribution_major_version == "7")
```

There has got to be a better solution than what I came up with, and it's hard to believe that everyone else encounters this and also puts up with it.  Is there something I need to configure in CentOS 7.x servers to prevent this?  Is there something in ansible that is needed to deal with this, such as multiple ssh attempts per play on first failure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you've seen it reset _existing_ ssh connections? Normally, restarting ssh is not supposed to affect existing connections, so this might be some sort of clue.

Comment: Please specify the exact ansible version you're using (e.g. if there _is_ a bug in the systemd module, people will be interested what version it was in).

Comment: @sourcejedi
ansible --version
ansible 2.2.0.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
 configured module search path = Default w/o overrides

Well, I mean it "could" be a bug, but if so, why am I the only one experiencing it?  Unless there is no one else out there using CentOS 7x with ansible.... You're right however in that a service refresh shouldn't affect existing connections.  Indeed, on my CentOS 6x servers, everything works flawlessly on the same playbook.

Comment: When you say it is restarted - in the system log, is that all you get?  Or does systemd report that sshd exited, and was restarted according to `Restart=on-failure`?  If so, what was the exit status?  And did sshd not log any error message?

Comment: This isn't an Ansible problem, but either an SSH or some network problem. Restarting SSH doesn't affect current SSH connections, so something else here is at play. Have you tried regularly connecting over SSH from the terminal, restart `sshd` and what happens with your connection? Also are you using SSH `ControlMaster` with Ansible? You can enable it in ansible.cfg `ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a common Problem.
[Patch for Ansible ssh retries from 2016](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/17754)

A better solution might be to wait for sshd to be ready to connect.
[Original thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/Ansible-project/bVt_KMIzBwg/RJ40_kD4soYJ) with this ansible code solution:

[VM creation tasks...]

- name: Wait for the Kickstart install to complete and the VM to reboot
    local_action: wait_for host={{ vm_hostname }} port=22 delay=30 timeout=1200 state=started

- name: Now configure the VM...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `systemd` module, try the `service` module:

```
- name: Restart secure shell daemon post configuration
  service: 
    name: sshd
    state: restarted
```

Comment: Interesting,  I will try that and get back to this page to let people know.  But doesn't the service module just manipulate the "service" binary which really just redirects through systemctl?  Well, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: DopeGhoti, sadly your suggestion did not work.  I get exactly the same issue as before, and it doesn't appear to be module dependent between the service, or systemd modules.  Anyone else have any suggestions?